# View is not updating when view model updates

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, view

I've been stuck at this for a while now, my view model is not updating the view. When I debug, the view model is updating but it isn't being displayed in the view. what am i doing wrong?

This is in my view:

```
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <viewModels:SalaryViewModel/>
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
                    <Label Text="{Binding sYear}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding sTransportation}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding sMonth}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
                    <Label Text="{Binding sBasicSalary}" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" />
```

When I run a Debug.WriteLine, The values are shown on the output panel in Visual Studio. It is only the view that is not getting the updated values. Below is the SalaryViewModel

```
 class SalaryViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private ApiServices _apiServices = new ApiServices();
        private string year;
        private string month;
        private string BasicSalary;
        private string Transportation;

        public string sYear
        {
            get { return year; }
            set
            {
                if (year == value)
                    return;
                year = value;
                onPropertyChanged(nameof(sYear));
            }
        }
        public string sMonth
        {
            get => month;
            set
            {
                if (month == value)
                    return;
                month = value;
                onPropertyChanged(nameof(sMonth));
            }
        }
        public string sBasicSalary
        {
            get =>BasicSalary;
            set
            {
                if (BasicSalary == value)
                    return;
                BasicSalary = value;
                onPropertyChanged(nameof(sBasicSalary));
            }
        }
        public string sTransportation
        {
            get => Transportation;
            set
            {
                if (Transportation == value)
                    return;
                Transportation = value;
                onPropertyChanged(nameof(sTransportation));
            }
        }


        public ICommand SalaryCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return new Command(async () =>
                {
                    string currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString();
                    string currentYear = DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
                    await _apiServices.FetchSalary(currentYear , currentMonth );
                });
            }
        }
        private void onPropertyChanged(string pName)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(pName));

        }

    }
```

Comment: You are not updating any of the values in this code? If you want the View tho have the updated values you need to set the values of the properties.

Comment: So i'm supposed to include these values in the await _apiServices line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Hi, i did see that you called "set" method of "sBasicSalary". How do
>   you set the value of sBasicSalary after calling  "await
>   _apiServices.FetchSalary(currentYear , currentMonth );"?

Comment: I'm new to this view model thing, and i think i'm getting it wrong. I have this included in my FetchSalary function:  SalaryViewModel svm = new SalaryViewModel(); and to change the value in the view model, I did this : svm.sBasicSalary = "Basic Salary: value"; is this wrong to do?

Comment: Am I suppose to inlcude all values in the await line and include them all in the FetchSalary Function?

Comment: i think you should not call this statement: "SalaryViewModel svm = new SalaryViewModel();", you should pass the instance of SalaryViewModel in "FetchSalary". e.g.  await apiServices.FetchSalary(this);

Comment: If i remove that line, the rest of the values will not be updated in the view model and will cause an error that the variable does not exist in the FetchSalary function, but I will however try to input all values in the await line, other than the current year and month, and edit my FetchSalary function.

Comment: e.g. await apiServices.FetchSalary(this,currentYear , currentMonth ); you FetchSalary function in ApiServices: public Task FetchSalary(SalaryViewModel svm,string currentYear,string currentMonth){svm.sBasicSalary = "Basic Salary: value"; }